# How to hide route id and params in angular2?

Tags: angular

This is my code:

```js
<a [routerLink]="['/detailhistory']" [queryParams]="{ 'path': item.path}">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

how to hide query params in browser url after redirected?

Comment: use Optional parameters which can be sent along the router body so it will not be seen on the URL

Comment: hot to do that? I have no idea about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `skipLocationChange` as a parameter which will keep the current URL.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/detailhistory']" [queryParams]="{ 'path': item.path}">{{ item.name }} [skipLocationChange]="true"</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<a [routerLink]="['/detail' ]" [queryParams]="{ 'path': item.path}" skipLocationChange></i></a>
```

This solved my issue.